# Uniqueness of solution to homogeneous second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y=y(x)$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$. The general solution to the equation 
$$y+ay'(x)+by''(x)=0$$
is
$$y(x)=c_1e^{\lambda_1 x} + c_2e^{\lambda_2 x}$$
where $\lambda_{1,2}\in \mathbb{C}$ are roots of the auxiliary equation.

How can I show that this is indeed the most general solution? This is something I've taken for granted until now.

Comment: Write it as a first order system. Solve the system using the diagonalization theorem. By the Picard-Lindelof theorem you have the result.

Comment: I've now got to the stage where I can apply the Picard-Lindelof theorem, but the proof of that theorem itself looks too difficult for me unfortunately!

Comment: Oh, once you've found a solution ( which you have), you only have to use the uniqueness part. Which can easily be proved with contradiction. Assume another solution exists, then use the mean value theorem, and the fact they satisfy the same IVP to deduce the unique. Note this procedure applies for $n$th oder equations word for word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For brevity let $F(y)=y+a y'+b y''$. For any fixed $x_0$ ,prove that $$[F(y)=0\wedge  y(x_0)= y'(x_0)=0]\iff y=0.$$ A proof can be found in any introductory text on this subject.Assuming $b\ne 0$, let $1+a x+b x^2=b(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)$ for all $x$. If $\lambda_1\ne \lambda_2$ let $f_i(x)=e^{\lambda_i x}$ for $i=1,2$. If $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$ let $f_1=e^{\lambda_1 x}$ and $f_2=x f_1$ .Now if $u$ is a solution of $F=0$ there exist $c_1,c_2$ such that $$u(x_0)-c_1 f_1(x_0)-c_2f_2(x_0)=u'(x_0)-c_1 f'_1(x_0)-c_2 f'_2(x_0)=0$$. So with $y=u-c_1f_1-c_2f_2$ we have $$F(y)=0\wedge y(x_0)=y'(x_0)=0.$$

Comment: Is $z$ also a solution? If so, why should $u-z$ = 0?

Comment: My typing and thinking were out of sync.Thanks. I fixed it.And I covered the case of repeated roots of the auxiliary equation.

Comment: Thanks for expanding, but still I don't understand why $u(x_0)-c_1f_1(x_0)-c_2f_2(x_0)=0$? Maybe it's obvious but it's been a while since I did any mathematics!

Comment: We have 2  linear equations in $c_1,c_2$.There does  exist a solution  for them. We choose the values that make y and y' vanish at $x_0$.

Comment: Oh ok! But doesn't this mean that if we picked say $x_1\neq x_0$ instead of $x_0$, that choice would give rise to different $c_1,c_2$, so that means the same $u(x)$ is equal to two different linear combinations of the exponentials?

Comment: No it won't. It might look like it but if $ c_1f_1+c_2f_2=c_1^*f_1+c_2^*f_2$  then $c_1=c_1^*$ and $c_2=c_2^*$. Note that if $u$ is a solution, and we know the values of $u(x_0)$ and $u'(x_0)$ then  it turns out that we cannot  arbitrarily choose the values of $u$ or $u'$ at another point. If we could we'd get different linear combinations, but $u$ is constrained by $F(u)=0$. I suggest you work through a numerical example,with specific values of $a$ and $b$ with different $x_0,x_1$.